# Save data on select_tag after append option by javascript on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

[image]

I have 2 select_tag with multiple: true as below.
When i select items left-side, then click "save" to move items to right-side (I used JS to do this).
How to save options added right-side.

My snipe code:

```js
 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('#move-right').click(function(event){
    $('#tableA').find('option:selected').detach().prop("selected", false).appendTo($('#tableB'));
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
  });

  $('#move-left').click(function(event){
    $('#tableB').find('option:selected').detach().prop("selected", false).appendTo($('#tableA'));
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="column-assign">
  <span>
     <%= select_tag :op, options_from_collection_for_select(@options, "id", "name"),:class => 'tableA',multiple: true,id: "tableA",:selected => @selectedoption %>
  </span>
 <span>
     <input type="button" value="&#8594;" class="move-right" id="move-right"/>
     <input type="button" value="&#8592;" class="move-left" id="move-left"/>
 </span>
      
 <span>
     <%= select_tag :ops, options_from_collection_for_select(@option, "id", "name"),:class => 'tableB',multiple: true, id: "tableB" %>
 </span>

 
</span>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: My question is : How to save data of select_tag added by JS ? Thanks

Comment: Please add a code snippet of what you are trying to do

Comment: If the above is in a form with your model, and the model has the attribute `ops`, then all you need to do is submit the form and the ops attribute will be updated with the values in the second select control.